# REST send back response once all methods are done

Tags: java, rest

Hello i am building a REST app with an react frontend and i got a problem that
i get an response way before all my methods in the REST have been executed

this is the REST

```
@POST
@Path("{userName}/{oysterName}/{backupFile}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createOyster(@PathParam("userName") String userName, @PathParam("backupFile") String backupFile,
                             @PathParam("oysterName") String oysterName, String version) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        NexusResource resource = mapper.readValue(version, NexusResource.class);
        restUtil.restoreDatabase(userName, backupFile);
        restUtil.createOyster(userName, oysterName);
        restUtil.installOyster(oysterName);
        restUtil.getVersionFromNexus(resource,oysterName);

        return Response.ok().build();

    }
}
```

the last methodcall resUtil.getVersionFromNexus can take quite a while. All the methods can take all from 3 min to 20 min to finish. What i want is that no matter how long it takes i only want to send the response when everything is done and ready. Should i make the last method return something or what is the best practice since this is my first time creating REST

```
   public void getVersionFromNexus(NexusResource version, String oysterName){
        Path unzipDirectory = util.getTempFolder("unzipped");
        TomcatNexusLayout.downloadZip(version, util.getTempFolder(version.getText()), c -> {
                        List<Path> customerFiles = TomcatNexusLayout.restUnzip(c, unzipDirectory);
                        Files.delete(c);
                        deployOysterVersion(oysterName, (ArrayList<Path>) customerFiles);
    });
    }

    private void deployOysterVersion(String oysterName, ArrayList<Path> esaFiles) {
        TomcatResource tomcatResource =
                new TomcatResource(oysterName, Paths.get(tomcatsPath).resolve(oysterName).toString());
        List<Path> esFile = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Path> warFiles= new ArrayList<>();
        List<Path> sqlFiles = new ArrayList<>();
         for (Path path: esaFiles){
             if(path.toString().contains("ncc") && path.toString().endsWith(".esa")){
                 esFile.add(path.toAbsolutePath());
             }
             else if(path.toString().endsWith(".war")) {
                     warFiles.add(path.toAbsolutePath());
             }
         }
        tomNexLay.restDeploy(esFile, tomcatResource,warFiles,sqlFiles);
        startOyster(oysterName);
    }

    private void startOyster(String oysterName){
        TomcatResource tomcatResource =
                new TomcatResource(oysterName, Paths.get(tomcatsPath).resolve(oysterName).toString());
       serCtrl.restStart(tomcatResource);
        System.out.println("HEJ HEJ");
    }
}
```

So this is the method sequence that is last called that takes time to finish. what i really need is that when it reached the print "HEJ HEJ" to then send the response. The part that takes time is this

```
TomcatNexusLayout.downloadZip(version, util.getTempFolder(version.getText()), c -> {
                    List<Path> customerFiles = TomcatNexusLayout.restUnzip(c, unzipDirectory);
                    Files.delete(c);
                    deployOysterVersion(oysterName, (ArrayList<Path>) customerFiles);
});
```

this makes it hard with CompleteableFuture as if i make the method into a CompleteableFuture it returns that its completed before the code block that takes time is done.

Comment: Maybe have a look at completablefutures: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: @Lino Using completeableFuture solved it after som tinkering! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked! You might also want to provide a self answer, so when others have a similar problem the can look it up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lino mentioned in the comments the solution to my problem were CompleteableFuture that makes sure everything is done before it returns anything.

so here is the solution

```
 public String getVersionFromNexus(NexusResource version, String oysterName, String customer) {
        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Path unzipDirectory = util.getTempFolder("unzipped");
        TomcatNexusLayout.downloadZip(version, util.getTempFolder(version.getText()), c -> {
            List<Path> customerFiles = TomcatNexusLayout.restUnzip(c, unzipDirectory);
            Files.delete(c);
            deployOysterVersion(oysterName, (ArrayList<Path>) customerFiles, customer);
            completableFuture.complete(startOyster(oysterName));
        });
        try {
            return completableFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "FAILED";
    }
```

so first i initialize the CompleteableFuture

```
 CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
```

then by making sure the last method is done

```
   completableFuture.complete(startOyster(oysterName));
    });
    try {
        return completableFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here i first make sure that completeableFuture.complete() wich basically returns a String and tells my completeableFuture that once i got the String i am all done

```
return completableFuture.get();
```

completeableFuture.get() is locked and does not to anything until there has been an completeableFuture.complete() fired. And once the complete is done the .get() gets unlocked and can return the String from startOyster() to the method that called it so my rest call now only responds once it has that String

Comment: Thanks for also explaining what is going on rather than just pasting your code.